# Linq to Entities with Repository Pattern and EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern, predicate

I have been recently working on a Entity Framework and Repository pattern, in the repository class i have created a function called find, which takes a predicate generates the entity out of it. here's my Repository function.

```
public T Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderby = null, string includeProperties = "")
{
    IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;
    if (filter != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(filter);
    }
    foreach(var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        query = query.Include(includeProperty);
    }

    if (orderby != null)
    {
        return orderby(query).First();
    }
    else
    {
        return query.First();
    }
}
```

Here's my DTO class.

```
public class UsersDo
{
    public int UserId {get;set}
    public string Username {get;set}
    ...
}
```

Now i am calling the Find function on my page like:

```
usersDao.Find(x=>x.Username == "username")
```

However i gets the error

```
The entity or complex type 'UsersDo' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.
```

Could anyone suggest what's going wrong here.

**EDIT**
under repository class, i have a constructor:

```
private readonly DbSet<T> dbSet;
private readonly DataContext context;
public GenericDao(DataContext _context)
{
    context = _context;
    dbSet = context.Set<T>();
}
```

my Dao class:

```
public class UsersDao : GenericDao<UsersDo>, IUsers
{
     public UsersDao(DataContext context) : base (context) {}
     ...
}
```

Comment: how do you know the correct dbSet? btw Entity Framework follows repository pattern by itself and **I dont suggest you to use External Repository Pattern** since it will lead to complexities, deficit functionalities, unwanted bugs and more. I can say that you will eventually go into a need of bypassing your Repository pattern

Comment: @Simonare updated my question, could you give me any reference as how i can use the default EF Repository pattern, with the above example i hope my concern would be clear.

Comment: can you try with `IQueryable<T> query = dbSet.AsQueryable();`?

Comment: @Simonare, that didn't worked, it's still throwing same error.

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend a simplified repository pattern that will help with mocking your data source for testing, and provide more flexibility. I do not recommend using generic repositories, but rather to treat a repository similar to a Controller. (I serve data for a particular set of operations) This cuts down on the number of dependency references, though favours SRP over DNRY.

For example:

```
public class OrderRepository : IOrderRepository
{
    private MyDbContext Context
    {
        return _contextLocator.Get<MyDbContext>() ?? throw new InvalidOperation("The repository must be called from within a context scope.");
    }

    IQueryable<Order> IOrderRepository.GetOrders()
    {
        var query = Context.Orders.Where(x => x.IsActive);
        return query;
    }

    IQueryable<Order> IOrderRepository.GetOrderById(int orderId)
    {
        var query = Context.Orders.Where(x => x.IsActive && x.OrderId == orderId);
        return query;
    }

    Order IOrderRepository.CreateOrder( /* Required references/values */)
    {
    }

    void IOrderRepository.DeleteOrder(Order order)
    {
    }
}
```

By returning IQueryable the consuming code can maintain control over optional filter criteria, sorting, paging, and operations against the data without triggering unnecessary data reads. There is no need for complicated expression parameters for filtering, sorting, or extra parameters to manage paging. The repository serves as the gate-keeper for required filters such as IsActive, authorization checks, etc. The repository also can serve as an entity factory, ensuring that all mandatory fields and references are provided when creating a new entity. I also let the repository manage the delete operations to ensure that all validation and integrity are enforced, plus auditing records, and handle soft-delete scenarios. (IsActive)

Some people shun the use of IQueryable on the grounds it "leaks" EF-isms into the controllers. However, it leaks them no more than complicated methods passing expressions in an attempt to abstract away EF. Every condition expression is equally vulnerable to needing to conform with EF-isms. (I.e. passing an order-by expression which references a private method on an entity or a static method)

The benefit of a repository pattern like this (versus just leaving code accessing DbSets) is ease of testing. A mocked repository just has to return a `List<T>` `AsQueryable` and your controllers etc. can be tested in isolation.  It also provides a nice centralization for required filters and operations against entities.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
public class UserContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<UsersDo> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<UsersDo>()
            .HasKey(e => e.UsersId);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

public class Repo<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly DbSet<T> dbSet;

    public Repo(DbContext context)
    {
        dbSet = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public T Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderby = null, string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;
        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }
        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderby != null)
        {
            query = orderby(query);
        }

        // If you use the First() method you will get an exception when the result is empty.
        return query?.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

------- Test the code

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var usersDao = new Repo<UsersDo>(new UserContext());

        var r = usersDao.Find(x => x.Username == "username");
    }
}
```

Comment: even FirstOrDefault doesn't works, rest of the code was similar.

Comment: I marked the property `UsersId` as Key in the DbContext, Did you see that?

Comment: Yeah but i have already have the UserId marked as key for my entity.
`[Key]
public int UserId {get;set;}
public string Username {get;set;}`

Comment: In you DbContext, Do you have a DbSet<UsersDo> ?

Comment: Yes i do have DbSet<UsersDo>

Comment: Also i have another Generic function `T Get(object Id)` and this works perfectly with `usersDao.Get(2)`, so probably it shouldn't be the UsersDo registration issue, correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I don't know what else I can do

Answer (score 0):

The problem is userDoa is not registered entity in your DbContext.

Also,

```
public class UsersDao : GenericDao<UsersDo>, IUsers
{
     public UsersDao(DataContext context) : base (context) {}
     ...
}
```

is not needed I believe. The problem is not related with your generic repository.

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
     public virtual DbSet<UserDo> UserDos { get; set; }
}

public class UserDo 
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId {get;set}

    public string Username {get;set}
}
```

then

```
var result = new UserContext().Find(x => x.Username == "John");
```

Comment: yes i do have UsersDo registered in DbContext, i am using Code first approach, and based on DbContext only it creates table in database, and my tables have been already successfully created.

Comment: Also i have another Generic function `T Get(object Id)` and this works perfectly with `usersDao.Get(2)`, so probably it shouldn't be the UsersDo registration issue, correct?

Comment: `public T Get(object id)
        {
            var find = context.Set<T>().Find(id);
            if (find != null)
                return find;
            return null;
        }`